# How to find and download attachment from the latest mail in an Outlook folder?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a folder created where all the mails are deposited based on a rule. The mail in the folder keeps accumulating everyday. I want to download the attachment from the latest mail in that folder. Currently, I am able to parse through all the files and download attachment from all the mails. How do I download only from the latest mail? Below is my code.

```
Sub FebAttachment_Click()
Const AttachmentPath As String = "D:\Documents and Settings\rahul.baskaran\Desktop\"
Dim oApp As Object, ONS As Object, OInb As Object
Dim OItem, OAtch As Object
Dim OFind As Object
Dim OMail As Object
Dim strName As String
Dim strExt As String


Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set ONS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OInb = ONS.Folders("Archive Folders").Folders("BIZOPS").Folders("2014.02")
Set OMail = OInb.Items
For Each OItem In OInb.Items

If OItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each OAtch In OItem.Attachments
            strName = OAtch.Filename
            strExt = Split(strName, ".z")(0)
            OAtch.SaveAsFile AttachmentPath & OAtch.Filename
            Exit For
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "The mail doesn't have an attachment"
        End If
Next OItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the items by the creation date (Items.Sort) in the descending order, then retrieve the first item in the collection.

Make sure your code operates on the same Items collection (retrieve OInb.Items once and cache it in a variable).

Comment: That's great. I used the sort and it worked once I changed this part from `For Each OItem In OInb.Items` to `For Each OItem In OMail` . Although I'm not sure how that mattered. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Every time you call MAPIFolder.Items, you end up with a brand new COM object that has no knowledge of any other instances of the same object. That is why I suggested to retrieve the Items collection only once - to make sure you call Sort and retrieve items from the same instance of the object.